# How to get list of all routes of a controller in Symfony2?

Tags: symfony, indexing, controller, routes, symfony-2.1

I have a controller which implements all **routes/URL(s)**.
I had the idea to offer a generic index over all help-pages.

Is there a way to get all routes defined by a controller (from within a controller) in `Symfony2`?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You could get all of the routes, then create an array from that and then pass the routes for that controller to your twig.

It's not a pretty way but it works.. for 2.1 anyways..

```
    /** @var $router \Symfony\Component\Routing\Router */
    $router = $this->container->get('router');
    /** @var $collection \Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection */
    $collection = $router->getRouteCollection();
    $allRoutes = $collection->all();

    $routes = array();

    /** @var $params \Symfony\Component\Routing\Route */
    foreach ($allRoutes as $route => $params)
    {
        $defaults = $params->getDefaults();

        if (isset($defaults['_controller']))
        {
            $controllerAction = explode(':', $defaults['_controller']);
            $controller = $controllerAction[0];

            if (!isset($routes[$controller])) {
                $routes[$controller] = array();
            }

            $routes[$controller][]= $route;
        }
    }

    $thisRoutes = isset($routes[get_class($this)]) ?
                                $routes[get_class($this)] : null ;
```

Comment: That's what I missed:
    $router = $this->container->get('router');
    $collection = $router->getRouteCollection();
    $allRoutes = $collection->all();
THX

Comment: But this would NOT display routes which have no name defined, eg. `@Route("/news")`.  When I tried your method as there were no `name="news_route"` parameter, I could not get this route mentioned. Anyone had similar problem?

Comment: As far as I know if you use annotations and don't declare a name then the name is auto generated from the bundle name, the controller name and the action name, (the use of `name=news_route` just overrides this default action). So for `Bills\BlogBundle`, `NewsController`, `indexAction` the name would be auto-generated as `bills_blog_news_index`.

Answer (score 146):

What you can do is use the cmd with (up to SF2.6)

```
php app/console router:debug
```

With SF 2.7 the command is

```
php app/console debug:router
```

With SF 3.0 the command is

```
php bin/console debug:router
```

which shows you all routes.

If you define a prefix per controller (which I recommend) you could for example use

```
php app/console router:debug | grep "<prefixhere>"
```

to display all matching routes

To display get all your routes in the controller, with basically the same output
I'd use the following within a controller (it is the same approach used in the router:debug command in the symfony component)

```
/**
 * @Route("/routes", name="routes")
 * @Method("GET")
 * @Template("routes.html.twig")
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function routeAction()
{
    /** @var Router $router */
    $router = $this->get('router');
    $routes = $router->getRouteCollection();

    foreach ($routes as $route) {
        $this->convertController($route);
    }

    return [
        'routes' => $routes
    ];
}


private function convertController(\Symfony\Component\Routing\Route $route)
{
    $nameParser = $this->get('controller_name_converter');
    if ($route->hasDefault('_controller')) {
        try {
            $route->setDefault('_controller', $nameParser->build($route->getDefault('_controller')));
        } catch (\InvalidArgumentException $e) {
        }
    }
}
```

routes.html.twig

```
<table>
{% for route in routes %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ route.path }}</td>
        <td>{{ route.methods|length > 0 ? route.methods|join(', ') : 'ANY' }}</td>
        <td>{{ route.defaults._controller }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

Output will be:

`/_wdt/{token}  ANY     web_profiler.controller.profiler:toolbarAction`
etc.

Comment: Sorry! I would like to access this information from within a controller, so that it can generate an index.

Comment: I doubt, that the routing component does care about the controller.

Comment: And that means? Is there a chance to get that information or not?

Comment: I strongly advice to read about routing and dependency injection in symfony, where your tools would be: http://symfony.com/doc/master/book/routing.html http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/introduction.html

Comment: I read that, but I was just looking for a way to get the configured routes of a controller from within a controller (php).
Qoop's answer helped. Thx

Comment: Even if it doesn't answer this question, it is useful. So, +1 :)

Comment: Sorry to repeat comment, but your method too seems to NOT display routes which have no name defined, eg. @Route("/news"). When I tried your method as there were no name="news_route" parameter, I could not get this route mentioned also by `router:debug`.. Any ideas?

Comment: Afaik a route needs to have a name. If it does not have one it will not be present. If you define that name manually or not is up to you though.

Comment: very usefull snippet

Comment: `php bin/console debug:router` work with version 4 as well

Answer (score 20):

I was looking to do just that and after searching the code, I came up with this solution which works for a single controller (or any ressource actually). Works on Symfony 2.4 (I did not test with previous versions) :

```
$routeCollection = $this->get('routing.loader')->load('\Path\To\Controller\Class');

foreach ($routeCollection->all() as $routeName => $route) {
   //do stuff with Route (Symfony\Component\Routing\Route)
}
```

Comment: interesting way to get all the actions ( routes ) for a controller.

Comment: Best answer by far

Answer (score 7):

If anyone is stumbling on this issue, this is how I exported the routes in the global twig scope (symfony 4).

#### `src/Helper/Route.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Helper;

use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouterInterface;

class Routes
{
    private $routes = [];

    public function __construct(RouterInterface $router)
    {
        foreach ($router->getRouteCollection()->all() as $route_name => $route) {
            $this->routes[$route_name] = $route->getPath();
        }
    }

    public function getRoutes(): array
    {
        return $this->routes;
    }
}
```

#### `src/config/packages/twig.yaml`

```
twig:
    globals:
        route_paths: '@App\Helper\Routes'
```

#### Then in your twig file to populate a javascript variable to use in your scripts

```
<script>
    var Routes = {
        {% for route_name, route_path in routes_service.routes %}
            {{ route_name }}: '{{ route_path }}',
        {% endfor %}
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 5):

In Symfony 4 i wanted to get all the routes including controller and actions in one list. In rails you can get this by default.

In Symfony you need to add the parameter `show-controllers` to the `debug:router` command.

If somebody looking for the same feature it can be get with:

```
bin/console debug:router --show-controllers
```

this will produce a list like the following

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------
Name                   Method    Scheme    Host     Path                    Controller
------------------------------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------
app_some_good_name     ANY       ANY       ANY      /example/example        ExampleBundle:Example:getExample
------------------------------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 2):

The safest way to proceed is to use the symfony controller resolver, because you never know if your controller is defined as a fully qualified class name, a service, or whatever callable declaration.

```
    foreach ($this->get('router')->getRouteCollection() as $route) {
        $request = new Request();
        $request->attributes->add($route->getDefaults());

        [$service, $method] = $this->resolver->getController($request);

        // Do whatever you like with the instanciated controller
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you needed to get the route information from within a Controller, you can make use of Symfony's Autowiring. If it is configured properly, you can just pass `RouterInterface` to any routes in a Controller.

```
#[Route('/', name: 'app_default')]
public function someRoute(RouterInterface $router): JsonResponse
{
    $routesPaths = [];

    foreach ($router->getRouteCollection()->all() as $routeName => $route) {
        $routesPaths["$routeName"] = $route->getPath();
    }

    return new JsonResponse([
        'availableRoutes' => $routesPaths,
    ]);
}
```

However if you need this logic in multiple Controllers you should encapsulate the logic in a seperate class like @C Alex did in one of his answers.