# List all published routes in Odoo 10

Tags: odoo-10

Is there a way to list routes for controllers in Odoo 10. Other MVC frameworks can do this, for example this can be done in Symfony: [Symfony2: get list of all routes of a controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15943780/symfony2-get-list-of-all-routes-of-a-controller)